# How to pass an array from .php file to .ts file in ionic 4

Tags: php, angular, api, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have an array in .php file and i want to pass that array to .ts file through service provider and print them using *ngFor in Ionic Angular4.

```
     $query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM master_user");
     $messages = array();
     if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
     while($message = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
         $messages[] = $message;
       }
     }
```

currently i am able to pass single value by below code:

```
echo '{"success":{"message":"success"}}';
```

In .ts file i am getting this value by the following code:

```
       "data.success.message";
```

Just like the above i want to pass the array value to .ts and access that array.Hope this code makes sense.Kindly help me with this

Comment: Can't you use query parameters?

Comment: i have tried using them..but am unable to pass that to .ts file @shadowman_93

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM master_user");
          $messages = array();
           if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
           while($message = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
               $messages[] = $message;

             }
           }

    echo JSon_encode($messages);
```

and in the ts file console it directly like this:

```
console.log(data);
```

after viewing data into the console you will come to know how to use it and you can iterate using *ngFor in the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return the array to you service provider you should format it to `json` using `json_encode`, if you do that you will be able to affect directly your result to your object in the front-end,
Your php code should be

```
echo json_encode($messages);
```

instead of

```
echo '{"success":{"message":"success"}}';
```

And in your service provider just retrieve the messages.